# Passing Data from ViewController to iOS email app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, email

Excuse me if im missing something I have only started this iOS dev yesterday. I have a basic application where a user can snap up to 3 pictures, these are held in 3 different UIImageViews, the app also retrieves the gps coordinates and changes these into an address.

What I want to do is be able to send these images and information to an email address.

Currently I have a send button which is linked to an action.

Thanks

```
- (IBAction)sendFinalItem:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"send button pressed");
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailcontroller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailcontroller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    NSString *email =@"MYEMAIL@MYEMAIL.CO.UK";
    NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:email, nil];
    [mailcontroller setToRecipients:emailArray];
    [mailcontroller setSubject:@"[Urgent]Potential Job, iPhone snapped"];
    [self presentViewController:mailcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:         (MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
     {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
         NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
         NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
         NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
        default:
       break;
     }

// Close the Mail Interface
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `MFMailComposeViewController`? There is a method for adding attachments.

Comment: I will have a look for that now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `sendFinalItem` method write this..

```
NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImageViewName.image, 0.5f);
[mailer addAttachmentData:dataImage mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Image_1.jpg"]
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

```
[mailer setMessageBody:yourTextView.text isHTML:NO];
```

You can set `isHTML` to `YES`.(If your `textview` contains *HTML data*.)

**EDIT:**

If you want good quality image then use `UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImageViewName.image)` instead of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImageViewName.image, 0.5f)`

Happy coding..

Comment: If you want good quality image then use UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImageViewName.image) instead of UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImageViewName.image, 0.5f) .. Enjoy coding...

Comment: Could you possibly tell me how to attach the textview aswell?

Comment: You can't attach the whole textview. Please be more descriptive. What you are trying to achieve ? Want to attach text to the mail composer ?

Comment: Yes I have a UITextView in my app, I want to take the text out of this and insert it to the message body of the email. Sorry if im not explaining it correctly.